# io.emit not sending return from promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

```
io.emit('runPython', FutureValue().then(function(value) {
  console.log(value); //returns 15692
  return value;  // socket sends: 42["runPython",{}]
}));
```

As above, I am trying to send 15692 on io.emit, but the promised function is not returning the value even though I can see the value in the console.

Here is FutureValue():

```
function FutureValue(){
var rate = 0.05;
var nper = 10;
var pmt = 100;
var pv = 100;
var result;

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  new PythonShell('future_value.py', jsc(options, {
    args: [rate, nper, pmt, pv]
  }))
  .on('message', resolve);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
io.emit('runPython', FutureValue().then(function(value) {
  console.log(value); //returns 15692
  return value;  // socket sends: 42["runPython",{}]
}));
```

Your emit is not sending the `value`, it's sending the Promise!

`value` is only available inside the callback function of `then()`, which would be called asynchronously **after** the promise has completed successfully. By the time you emit the event, you only have a `Promise` in hand and no result yet.

Answer (score 1):

You currently pass a promise as 2nd argument to the `emit` method, not the resolved value.

Instead, invoke the `emit` when the promise resolves:

```
FutureValue().then(function(value) {
  console.log(value); //returns 15692
  io.emit('runPython', value);
});
```

Or shorter (without the `console.log`):

```
FutureValue().then(io.emit.bind(io, 'runPython'));
```